# Is there a reason to use const_cast on a string literal in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, const-cast

I'm looking at some sample code for an API I'm about to start using. The following pattern has me a bit confused:

```
char* str;
str = const_cast<char*>("Hello World");

printf("%s ", str);
```

(actually there's a huge case statement in which `str` is assigned in each case.)

Note that `printf` takes `const char*`. Is there any reasonable purpose for this convoluted conversion? The authors of this code are applying lots of performance oriented tricks elsewhere, but there is no explanation for what's going on here.

My instinct is to change this code to:

```
const char* str;
str = "Hello World";

printf("%s ", str);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Change it.  The original code is dangerously close to undefined behavior land.

Comment: Yeah `puts` doesn't quite do the same thing. Why would `puts` be a better choice in other situations though?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Oh, yeah, that was nonsense, nevermind.

Comment: I read the supposed duplicate question before posting this. None of the answers there directly address my question though. Obviously it's legal -- as the other question asks. I'm asking if there is a good reason to use this pattern in any case.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I forgot that `puts` appends a newline (never used it before), but note that GCC [optimizes a statement like `printf("blabla\n")` to `puts("blabla")`](http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string literal is a non-const `char[N]` in C, and a `const char[N]` in C++. Earlier versions of the C++ standard made special allowance for a `const` string literal to be assigned to a non-const `char*` for backwards compatibility with C.  However, this behavior was deprecated in C++03 and is now illegal in C++11 without an explicit cast, such as the one shown.

If you are only interested in C++11, you should change `str` to `const char*`.  Otherwise, you can use the cast for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect this is the backstory. The code in question has lots of cross-platform warts. I'm using C++11, but this code probably goes back to before C++03. What is the distinction you make between const and readonly? I've often wondered what would happen if you attempted to modify a string literal.

Comment: @Drew The language may allow you to modify it, but that doesn't mean it's safe to do so.

Comment: @remyabel, agreed. But what are you actually changing in this case? If a string literal is duplicated in code, and the compiler consolidates them within the executable, would this be changing another instance? Might that area of memory be protected? I suppose the answer to these questions is 'it depends' :)

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Like I said, a string literal is read-only data (stored in read-only memory, undefined behavior if you try to modify it), but not all compilers actually treat a string literal as a `const char[]`, some treat it as `char[]` instead. I make the distinction because there is one. You cannot normally assign a `const char*` to a `char*`, for instance, but assigning a `const char[]` *literal* to a `char*` is a special case.

Comment: There is no C98. There is C++98, C89 and C99.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible reason could be that `printf` requires `char*` in some particular implementation. Which, after some research, seems not to be the case. On the other hand, having a pointer to non-const `char` pointing at a string literal is dangerous as modifying a string literal triggers undefined behavior. If it works without the cast there is no reason to have it there and you should change it rightaway.